# C# ASP.NET MVC - Unable to get the properties/data of POST data I received from the frontend

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model

From the front end I am sending a POST request with the following data that I cannot change the structure of:

[image]

I am trying to get the "filter" data.

I created a Model for the following data as follows:

```
namespace Project.Models
{
    public class FooBar
    {
        public int skip { get; set; }
        public int page { get; set; }
        public Object filter { get; set; }

    }
}
```

However when trying to extract the data from the POST request I get the skip/page variables but just get {object} for filter that I am unable to expand upon

[image]

The controller I have is written like:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Foo([FromBody] FooBar request)
{
...

}
```

Why am I unable to expand the object or access any properties of it and how can I change this?

Comment: Where is your java script code?

Comment: @TanvirArjel I feel its not relevant https://pastebin.com/VdqBzV5S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reproduce request structure in your model and use it as action parameter.

```
public class FilterPageModel  {
    public int skip { get; set; }
    public int page { get; set; }
    public Filter filter{ get; set; }
}   

public class Filter
{         
    public string logic{ get; set; }
    public List<FieldFilter> filters{ get; set; }
}

public class FieldFilter
{         
    public string field{ get; set; }
    public string operator{ get; set; }
    public string value{ get; set; }
}
```

And then in controller:

```
public ActionResult Foo (FilterPageModel model){
    //...
}
```